# How can I assess the validity of a time-temperature superposition (TTS) master curve obtained from stress relaxation experiments?

Tags: material-science, polymers

I'm working on analyzing the viscoelastic behavior of a elastomer using time-temperature superposition (TTS) techniques based on stress relaxation experiments. I've come across various conditions for checking the validity of TTS plots created through the application of frequency, such as the smoothness of Van-Gurp Palmen and Cole-Cole plots and the fitting of shift factors (aT) to WLF or Arrhenius equations. However, I'm uncertain about how to specifically assess the validity of a TTS master curve derived from stress relaxation data for elastomers.

Could someone provide guidance on the key steps or considerations involved in evaluating the validity of a TTS master curve obtained from stress relaxation experiments, especially when dealing with elastomers?